# Как сделать выборку в SQL

Tags: sql, plsql-developer

У меня есть таблица INFO с полями ID, Parent_id, Name_object. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как объединить (Без использования написания собственных функций), чтобы кол-во строк сохранилось так же 3, но при этом в поле Name_object добавить наименование родительских полей, т.е
в ID 655 - Name Сад-во Энергетик,
в ID 168057 - Name Сад-во; 4,
и в ID 698 - Name Сад-во; 4; Рябиновая.

Comment: Укажите точно СУБД, включая точную версию.

Comment: Запрос на обновление. В качестве источника данных будет запрос с рекурсивным СТЕ, который строит полный путь.

Comment: СУБД oracle 12c

Answer (score 0):

Это будет что-то типа

```sql
MERGE INTO info
USING (
  WITH cte (id, parent_id, path) AS (
    SELECT id, parent_id, name_object
    FROM info
    WHERE parent_id IS NULL
  UNION ALL
    SELECT info.id, info.parent_id, cte.path || '; ' || info.name_object
    FROM cte
    JOIN info ON (cte.id = info.parent_id)
    )
  SELECT id, path
  FROM cte
  ) data ON (data.id = info.id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET info.name_object = data.path;
```

---

А если нужна только выборка - берёшь только подзапрос.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Почитаю про CTE. Помогло

Comment: @ДаниярКоптлеуов https://habr.com/ru/post/43955/